# Pentaho - CDE How to use a one datasource with one execution for two components

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-cde, pentaho-design-studio

I have a chart component and a table component. Both are pointing to same query. When I load the dashboard the same query executes twice for bar and table component.

So the execution time got delay in this.

How to avoid this delay?

I tried to assign into a parameter, But i don't find a way to render chart based on result variable.

How to use one component's data output to another component without executing the same query again?

Could you please suggest any idea or workaround!!

Thanks,

Comment: Just give me your suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Standard way is to use a Query component to make the query and then have the other two components get that data.

Note, though, that in your current setup the second query will hit the cache so the delay might not be that big.